# How modify a control on a different form?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I need to use the contents of the first column of a JTable to set the values in a JComboBox drop-down list.
The issue is that the JTable is in a different Form (JFrame) so the private JComboBox is not directly accessable.
How can I send a signal and/or event from the JTable Form to the JComboBox Form to let it know that it needs to update it's dropdown contents? I'm not concerned about the data, I can make a public String[] or something, but how do I properly notify the JComboBox that it needs update itself?

Comment: If you need to access the combobox from outside the jframe, make it public. Better yet, add a public method that returns its value.

Comment: Can't seem to make the JComboBox public. It is a swing control I used from the netbeans palette. I tried a public method to return the JComboBox model to the form that want to change it but the compiler complains that a non-static variable cannot (the JComboBox) cannot be reference from a static context.

Comment: You can add a Listener to the combobox, and let it update your state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to use the contents of the first column of a `JTable` to set the values in a `JComboBox` drop-down list. The issue is that the `JTable` is in a different Form (`JFrame`) so the private `JComboBox` is not directly accessible.

And why would the `JComboBox` and the `JTable` should have access to each other ? Those are only view components. What will happen if you want to show the combobox without showing the table (e.g. in testing) ? If it retrieves it data directly from the `JTable` you have a serious problem.
The moment you created your `JTable` you had a `TableModel` containing the actual data of the `JTable`. It is that model (or at least the data in that model) that should be shared.

So let the model for the combobox and the model for the table share the same data, and all will be well.

Comment: What you say is correct. The table data is saved to a file. But I've been tasked with a way to update the combo box contents when the user makes a change to the table. The form containing the table is not normally visible, only when it needs to be changed. Changes to the table are saved to a file which the comboBox can update from, but the comboBox needs to know when to update. I'm trying to find the ActionListener tutorial but the page is [missing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/post1.0/ui/eventmodel.html).

Comment: @jacknad The `TableModel` fires events when data is changed. You can add a listener to that model

Comment: Getting back to your original answer, I'll let the combobox and table share the same data. Now I just need to figure out how to modify the combobox with the shared data as it opens, but that is a different problem. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

The Swing MVC model would say that you should update the model objects.  When the JComboBox is redisplayed, it sees the new model values.

Comment: The model objects are private. How do I let the JComboBox know that it needs to update its model from a different form?

Comment: The model is something that should be shared across UI elements.  They should be given the information they need to display.